How can I display non-translated fields, values, terms etc. instead of hiding them?
I enabled i18 and localization modules on my Drupal 10 site, so now the user can switch languages if a translation is available.
I have some Views on the site that pull in a big location taxonomy (eg World-> Europe->Sweden...) that is English only, and Drupal is hiding non translated terms in the view. How could I display non translated fields,  values, terms etc instead of hiding them?



Live URLs are not allowed. Context gets lost after you fixed the problem.

Thanks. Hmm interesting. I guess I will have to translate the location vocabulary  gonna be a little investment. 60000 location terms into dozens of languages.
Alternatively, I might hack the view so it links to the taxonomy term url instead of the translated url alias.

PS I tried the https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_language_fallback module but doesn't help it seems.

PS2 Alternatively, probably will figure out some geonames import script
https://www.geonames.org/AL/other-names-for-albania.html

PS3 I might have found sg https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_translation_fallback
